# Why is my cloth material not rendering properly?

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to get a background material (flag) to move with the wind and whenever I render a specific frame, it's OK.  But if I render as a video (xvid), it stays completely still.  Any idea why this might be?  Attached is the .blend file.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: When rendering an animation you need to press Animation instead of Render of pressing F12. (found here http://i.imgur.com/P7Yaitg.png) Did you press Animation or something else?

Comment: Yes I pressed Animation.  Good point though.

Comment: Is this what it's supposed to look like? http://sendvid.com/6nid80fq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the misunderstanding - you meant that the flag does not move. I thought you meant the image. It is good habit to **cache all physics** simulation before rendering, so the renderer has all the data needed to render the animation. Go to the **Physics pane** with the flag selected check **'Disk Cache'** and after that hit **'Bake'** in the **Cloth Cache tab**. After completing the caching process you can render and everything works just fine. It should look similar to the image below before rendering

[image]

Comment: It worked! I never knew that about physics...man what a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

I did select RGB as an output color format. Not sure why it is not selected by default, but it solved the problem for me. I can open it in the movie clip editor in Blender just fine. What software did you use to watch the rendered clip?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.  I used VLC media player.  It definitely played properly but the flag didn't render with the wind effect (just stayed as a plane).  Are you saying when you selected RGB as an output, it allowed the flag to have motion?

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot?

Comment: misunderstanding - I posted the solution below